# Laravel's nested relation first element

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, so after much googling... I have come across a unique case for Laravel.

I want to obtain the first element of the collection (not an array) and then with the nested relation also obtain the first element.

For example:

```php
auth()->user()->marks()->with('subjects', function($q) {
  $q->first();
})->first();
```

returns (note that subjects is an `array` but the code states `first`)

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Ahsan",
   "mark": 369,
    ...
   "subjects": [{...}]
}
```

Instead the query should have returned (b/c `$q->first()` returns the first element):

```json
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Ahsan",
   "mark": 369,
    ...
   "subjects": {...}
}
```

Qq: How can I modify the query to get the first subject without complicating the query? Am I missing something crucial here regarding `with` and `first`?

Aside:
Marks is One-to-Many relation. 369 can return multiple subjects if needed, but since I require the first it should be an `element` not an `array of single element`.

Comment: if you have specifiec your relation as a `hasMany` then it will return an array, try changing it to a `hasOne`

Comment: I see what you mean but it's actually `Marks::subjects<-belongToMany` - ie: Mark belongs to Many Subjects (or The Subjects that belong to the Marks) Can you explain why it should become `hasOne`? From my understanding, `hasMany` is a relation but when we query `->first()` should return the element as per doc.

Comment: Using `first()` is the same as using `limit(1)`. The relationship is a hasMany so you'll get an array with 1 element.

Comment: @IGP yes, and no. Yes, `limit(1)` but it shouldn't be an array. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-first "... first element in the collection. ..." And it can be seen when the second `->first()` run we only get the marks `first` element which isn't true `with` and `first`.

Comment: We understand your concern, but it is by design, if your relation has the word "many" in its declaration then it must return an array.

Comment: @DevMan Oh I see, when you say by design is this documented or implied through the hasMany relation - ie: return array even if `first` is requested? This then means the `first()` isn't really working as an element but returning an array of a single element! However, that defeats the purpose of `first` here. Is there a reason this design makes sense? B/c the first on many `Marks` is the first element.

Comment: @ziaahsan have you tried use this feature: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many?

Comment: How about querying it inverse

Comment: try using `->first()` in the relation declaration itself

Comment: @MirafzalShavkatov @xenooooo  and @DevMan, thank you all! With your help, I figured out the issue. Since my `Marks` and `Subject` table are linked through `belongsToMany` via a `pivot` table there is actually no way out of this - ie: The expected behavior of `ManyToMany`. The solution, as suggested by other devs: Switch to `HasMany` from the docs and use `latestOfMany` or `oldestOfMany` and Tada  Thank you!!